# Relations in Eloquent

Tags: php, eloquent, twig, slim

I have 3 tables; items, locations and item_stock.

I have been trying to figure out how to get the current stock on that location of the product when selecting a location.

The items and locations tables both has a ID column. This is the item_stock table:
[image: item_stock table]

How am I able to select all item_stock rows for that specific item and location combination?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using a local scope on LocationController that searches the item_stock table if item_id has been set by the form.